# « Alexandre, en mars 2021 » ou « Alexandre, mars 2021 » ?

Tags: grammaire, formulation-idiomatique, dates

Cette question m'est venue à l'esprit lorsque je traduisais la date et signature d'un avant-propos. Le format d'écriture de la date sans le jour ne m'est pas familier. Quelle forme est correcte ?

Comment: "Alexandre, mars 2021." coniendra dans la majorité des cas. Le groupe nominal "en mars 2021", sera plutôt utilisé dans une phrase complète : *En mars 2021, Alexandre se rendit à Athènes*.

Comment: Je vous remercie :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

À lire sur *[Termium Plus](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_d&page=9lcOojjUrxt8.html#date-part)* :

> **Date partielle (mois et année)**
> Dans un titre, un en-tête ou un bas de page, ou encore au début d’une phrase ou d’un paragraphe, on voit parfois une date partielle ne contenant pas le jour du mois. Dans ce cas, comme tout autre mot, le mois prend la majuscule initiale :
>
> Avril 2016

Dans ton cas, bien sûr, vu que le nom du mois est précédé d'une autre indication suivie d'une virgule, il ne faut pas de majuscule au nom du mois.

> Alexandre, mars 2021.

Et comme le dit @Graffito *en* ne convient pas ici. *En* introduirait un complément de temps, par exemple « J'ai rédigé cet avant-propos en mars 2021. » ou tout simplement « rédigé en mars 2021 ».

Voici la [préface des *Contemplations*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Contemplations/Pr%C3%A9face) signée par l'auteur (V.H.) et suivie du lieu et mois de rédaction :

[image]

Comment: Merci pour la clarté de votre réponse !